# Keyboard input not woorking on applications

Tags: keyboard

I am running ubuntu version 17.10. Recently the keyboard input stopped working only on specific applications. I can still use keyboard input on login screen and searching files on explorer, libre office document, text editor, terminal etc. But if i open any app like chrome or visual code. It isn't working. Give me any suggestions to resolve this problem and also if you know why this can happen let me know.

Thanks for your help in advance.